# conditional formatting in excel 2019

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format the entire row using condition that, if value in column B is greater than in column L then highlight row with green color, but i am getting wrong output.[image]
row 19 is highlighted even when condition is false

Comment: Use `=$B1>$L1`. You have a mismatch between your formula and the range applied to. If you're applying it to the entire column, then use row `1` as the reference instead of row `2`. Or change the applies to range to start in row `2`.

Comment: @BigBen https://stackoverflow.com/q/65879870/14713550