# open all hyperlinks from selected column at once in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open all the hyperlinks in a column at once,

code i used is

```
Sub OpenLinks()
Dim HL As Hyperlink
For Each HL In Selection.Hyperlinks
HL.Follow
Next
End Sub
```

this macro works fine when i select the cell containing [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
but dont work when I select cell next to it and run the macro

i have created the links mentioned in green and red column using the formula from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65867184/14713550

**edit**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking something below. Follow-up from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65867184/14713550) for `VBA` macro you need to convert all text to a valid URL. Here output from `Hyperlink()` will not work while direct hyperlink to the cell will work. There is big difference between hyperlink to cell and formula to the cell. So, using some VBA functions you have to concatenate all text to a single string then launch that hyperlink using `ActiveSheet.FollowHyperlink` or `ThisWorkBook.FollowHyperlink` method. Give a try on my below sub then let me know your feedback.

```
Sub OpenMyLink()
Dim strURL As String, fixedURL As String
Dim rng As Range
    
    fixedURL = "https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:"

    For Each rng In Selection
        strURL = fixedURL & Replace(Replace(rng, "&", "_", 1, 1), "-", "_", 1, 1) & "1!"
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink strURL
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: tried this, and it did work ! thank you so much sir.